# Converting Rackspace Cloud Files CDN URLs from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: php, replace, rackspace-cloud

I have a series of Rackspace Cloud Files CDN URLs stored which reference an HTTP address and I would like to convert them to the HTTPS equivalent.

Rackspace Cloud Files CDN URLs are in the following format:

**[http://c186397.r97.cf1.rackcdn.com/CloudFiles Akamai.pdf](http://c186397.r97.cf1.rackcdn.com/CloudFiles%20Akamai.pdf)**

And the SSL equivalent for this URL would be:

**[https://c186397.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/CloudFiles Akamai.pdf](https://c186397.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/CloudFiles%20Akamai.pdf)**

The changes to the URL are ([source](http://www.rackspace.com/blog/rackspace-cloud-files-cdn-launches-ssl-delivery/)):

1. HTTP becomes HTTPS
2. The second URI segment ('r97' in this example) becomes 'ssl'

The 'r00' part seems to vary in length (as some are 'r6' etc.) so I'm having trouble converting these URLs to HTTPS. Here's the code I have so far:

```
function rackspace_cloud_http_to_https($url)
{
    //Replace the HTTP part with HTTPS
    $url = str_replace("http", "https", $url, $count = 1);

    //Get the position of the .r00 segment
    $pos = strpos($url, '.r');

    if ($pos === FALSE)
    {
        //Not present in the URL
        return FALSE;
    }

    //Get the .r00 part to replace
    $replace = substr($url, $pos, 4);

    //Replace it with .ssl
    $url = str_replace($replace, ".ssl", $url, $count = 1);

    return $url;
}
```

This however does not work for URLs where the second segment is of a different length.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function rackspace_cloud_http_to_https($url)
{
    $urlparts = explode('.', $url);

    // check for presence of 'r' segment
    if (preg_match('/r\d+/', $urlparts[1]))
    {
        // replace appropriate segments of url
        $urlparts[0] = str_replace("http", "https", $urlparts[0]);
        $urlparts[1] = 'ssl';

        // put url back together
        $url = implode('.', $urlparts);
        return $url;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tested this and it works with different length parts. Thank you.

Comment: Cheers, there may be some syntax errors since I wrote it off the top of my head, but glad it works!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but if you are using this library: https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud you can use the getPublicUrl() method on the object, you just need to use the following namespace

```
use OpenCloud\ObjectStore\Constants as Constant;

// Code logic to upload file
$https_file_url = $response->getPublicUrl(Constant\UrlType::SSL);
```

Comment: How to know if you have poor documentation: you stumble across a relevant Stack Overflow answer from 5 years before finding it in the official documentation.